# Control height of Column within Row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Trying to get the Column within the Row to take the full height of the Row (as seen in the image)
The Column takes the min height needed but surely there's a way to make it expand the full height of the Row widget? I tried using Expanded but that didn't work.

I want it to take the full height of the Row as then the elements within the Column can be alignment according to `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` but at the moment as it takes the min height the elements are all be bunched up together.

```
    return new Container(
        child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                child: Text(
                  client.days[0].dayofLog,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 35,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new AnimatedCircularChart(
                  key: _chartKey,
                  size: const Size(300.0, 300.0),
                  initialChartData: buildGraphElements(client),
                  chartType: CircularChartType.Radial,
                  edgeStyle: SegmentEdgeStyle.round,
                  percentageValues: true,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                      height: 42.0,
                      width: 42.0,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      height: 42.0,
                      width: 42.0,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      height: 42.0,
                      width: 42.0,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      height: 42.0,
                      width: 42.0,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ],
                )
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    ));
```

[row size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Agdc.png)

[expanded size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAjgO.png)

Comment: What about `mainAxisSize`? Also, where did you place the `Expanded` widget?

Comment: I placed the ```Expanded``` widget instead of the initial ```Container``` widget which is the parent of the ```Column```.... but still did not work

Comment: Place the `Expanded` widget above the `Column` with the `mainAxisAlignment` set to `spaceBetween`

Comment: See https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNcZo.png for the expanded widget result as it still did not work. Still not taking the full height of the row

Comment: Adding ```mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max``` to the ```Row``` widget also did not work.

Comment: Try adding that to the Column. See here: https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041

Comment: Strangely this still didn't work...

Comment: Do you need the ListView at the top? It looks like right under it you just have a Column so I don't see a reason. If you need to scroll, just use `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't make a difference. The ```Expanded``` widget is still not taking the height of the ```Row``` widget for some reason. I've updated the images in my question so maybe what I'm trying to achieve is a bit more clear

Comment: I've made this, it works without the ListView: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/c1428bb9063e23bd269c1b05c60a3464

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
```

and at the time of assigning them to your variables you can multiply them by the% of screen you create as necessary.

If possible post a photo with the expected result.

Comment: I've added this in but this still hasn't resolved my issue. I've updated the images in my question so hopefully it makes it more clearer. I'm trying to get the individual boxes in the 2nd ```Column``` to have equal space around them using ```mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween```. However this doesn't work because the ```Column``` doesn't take the height of the ```Row```.